# How to sign a transaction using metamask or other wallets in nethereum

Tags: tokens, wallets, dapps, nethereum

I searched a lot on the internet and in the documentation, but I still haven't found the answer to my question.

I want to know how to sign a transaction through an external wallet using the nethereum library.

Like other Dapp projects, such as the Pancake Swap site, when you want to execute a transaction, the wallet opens and allows the transaction to be made, and after the transaction is confirmed, it is done.

How to open the user's wallet to confirm the transaction using the nethereum library so that the user can confirm the transaction?

And how can it be done that, like other dapps, the user can register on the site with his own external wallet, such as Metamask or other wallets, and confirm and execute transactions?

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how to sign a transaction through an external wallet using the nethereum library.

Only web pages can interact with MetaMask, because MetaMask is a web browser plugin.

Web pages are written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Nethereum is a C# framework, and cannot be used to write web pages. Thus, interacting with MetaMask from Nethereum is impossible or very difficult.

The correct solution is to create a frontend for your Dapp using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I implemented a website for my dapp using ASP.NET Core, and naturally the front end of the site is HTML, CSS and JavaScript codes, now I don't know how to make the user use Metamask or other wallets to register or logIn and sign the transactions?

Thank you for guiding me, friend

Comment: For login with MetaMask see [Sign in with Ethereum](https://login.xyz/).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. Please do not forget to mark the question answered if you have what you need.